# undefined reference to `memcpy'

Tags: eclipse, gcc, arm

I strougle a little bit with my eclipse-arm-project. I get the following errors.

```
undefined reference to `__aeabi_uldivmod'
undefined reference to `memcpy'
```

I know the right gcc-lib is missing but I don't know which the right would be and how I could configure eclipse correct to use it.

At the moment I have this relating paths in my project-PATH-variable

```
C:\...\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\Build Tools\2.8-201611221915\bin (for make)
C:\...\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\5_4_2016q3\bin (for arm-none-eabi-gcc)
```

The 'Build tools folder' and the 'Toolchain folder' are the same as the second path from the both project-PATH-variable.

I tested a lot of stuff and am now totally confused, may I ask for a little help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Solution:

In the project settings ('C/C++ Build' -> 'Settings' -> 'Tool-Settings' -> 'Cross ARM C++ Linker' -> 'Gernal') the following flags were active and has to be deactivated.

- Do not use default libraries (-nodefaultlibs)
- No startup or default libs (-nostdlib)